# How to declare `@Transactional` in a Spring Boot service so exception is thrown "immediately"?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

Say I have the following spring beans in a spring boot app. My intent is to make `createFoo()` transactional so:

1. When `barService.bar()` throws exceptions, the persist gets rolled back.
2. When the persist throws exception, the exception propagates up to the caller "immediately" so **`barService.bar()` is NOT called**.

```java
@Service
public class FooService
{
    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BarService barService;

    @Transactional
    public void createFoo(Foo foo) {
        fooRepository.save(foo);
        // expect to not execute when the above line throws exceptions
        barService.bar();
    }
}

@Service
public class BarService {
    public void bar() {

    }
}
```

So far the 1st requirement works, however the 2nd doesn't. When the persist throws exception, **`barService.bar()` is AlWAYS called**.

If I remove `@Transactional`, 2nd requirement works, the 1st doesn't.

I also tried all `Propagation` types, none of them work as I expected. For example, if I use `@Transactional(MANDATORY)`, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory'
```

Comment: Mandatory means there needs to be a pre-existing transaction, based on what you've said, that has nothing to do with your problem.  The behaviour you describe doesn't make sense with the code you've posted.  The `@Transactional` triggers an interceptor, which cannot alter the internal behaviour of your `createFoo` method.  You have something else going on.  If `fooRepository.save` throws an exception, `barService.bar()` will not be called, `@Transactional` will not affect that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Taylor. My observation is that, as I said in the question, if I remove `@Transactional`, `barService.bar()` is not called when the persist throws exception. Otherwise it will always get called. So `@Transactional` does seem to affect that under my observation.

Comment: @Taylor: this makes sense for errors like RI constraint violations where the save isn’t flushed to the dB until the end of the transaction. This is a JPA feature called transactional write-behind.

Comment: @NathanHughes Ahhh, so `fooRepository.save(foo);` is not actually throwing an exception, the txn commit is throwing the exception.  Yes, you're right, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `@Transactional`, each call to a repo method is a standalone transaction and it will be flushed immediately. That's why your 2nd requirement worked without `@Transactional`.

When you add `@Transactional`, the whole `createFoo()` becomes one single unit of transaction. Hence, the changes you make when calling `save()` will only be flushed when `createFoo()` completes its execution. That's why your 1st requirement worked with `@Transactional`.

To achieve what you want, keep `@Transactional` and call `saveAndFlush()` instead of `save()`.

Comment: Very well explained. `saveAndFlush` is exactly what I need. It works now. Thanks a lot! @Mr.J4mes

Comment: @LiangZhou glad I could help :)